# Convert many argparse conditional arguements to a more pythonic solution

Tags: python, arguments, command-line-interface, argparse

I am working on a cli application using python. I have a set of arguments that are mutually exclusive and a set of arguments that must be there if one of those mutually exclusive arguments is passed.
I have got it working using brute force and lengthy `if` conditions, but I feel like there is a neat way to do this. Researching about that told me *subparsers* might be useful, however I am not able to correctly use *subparsers* at all.
The conditions I want are the following-
**Main activities**
+-----+--------+--------+--------+---------+
| get | create | delete | update | remove  |
+-----+--------+--------+--------+---------+

These main activities are **mutually exclusive**.

If **get** is specified, then there should **not** be any more arguements.
If **delete** is specified then there should **not** be any more arguements.
If **remove** is specified then `-r` is **mandatory**.
If **update** is specified then `-f` **mandatory**, and`-cd` is **optional**.
If **create** is specified, then `-d` is **mandatory**, `-m` and `-f` are **optional** where `-m` and `-f` are **mutually exclusive**.

The brute force code is as follows -

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Check args')
#get
parser.add_argument('-g', '--get', help='')
#create
parser.add_argument('-c', '--create', help='')
parser.add_argument('-d', '--display', help='')
parser.add_argument('-m', '--message', help='')
parser.add_argument('-f', '--file', help='')
#update
parser.add_argument('-u', '--update', help='')
parser.add_argument('-cd', '--changed', help='')
#delete
parser.add_argument('-del', '--delete', help='')
#remove
parser.add_argument('-rm', help='')
parser.add_argument('-r', '--remove', help='')

args = vars(parser.parse_args())

if args['get'] is not None:
    if args['create'] is None and args['display'] is None and args['message'] is None and args['file'] is None and args['update'] is None and args['changed'] is None and args['delete'] is None and args['rm'] is None and args['remove'] is None:
        print(args['get'])
    else:
        print('Dont mix get with others')
        exit()

if args['create']:
    if args['get'] is None and args['message'] is None and args['file'] is None and args['update'] is None and args['changed'] is None and args['delete'] is None and args['rm'] is None and args['remove'] is None:
        print(args['create'])
    else:
        print('Dont mix create with others')
        exit()
    if args['display'] is None:
        print('Missing display')

if args['update']:
    if args['get'] is None and args['create'] is None and args['display'] is None and args['message'] is None and args['delete'] is None and args['rm'] is None and args['remove'] is None:
        print(args['update'])
    else:
        print('Dont mix update with others')
        exit()
    if args['file'] is None:
        print('Missing file')

if args['delete']:
    if args['get'] is None and args['create'] is None and args['display'] is None and args['message'] is None and args['file'] is None and args['update'] is None and args['changed'] is None and args['rm'] is None and args['remove'] is None:
        print(args['delete'])
    else:
        print('Dont mix delete with others')
        exit()

if args['rm']:
    if args['get'] is None and args['create'] is None and args['display'] is None and args['message'] is None and args['file'] is None and args['update'] is None and args['changed'] is None and args['delete'] is None:
        print(args['rm'])
    else:
        print('Dont mix resource management with others')
        exit()
    if args['remove'] is None:
        print('Missing remove')
```

Is there any way to make it more pythonic ?

**EDIT 1:**
Why have I not included code using *subparser* ?
Because so far I have understood, subparsers don't themselves take any values. So in my case I want to be able to execute the script like this -

- `prog -g xxyy`
- `prog -c xxyy -d 'Hello World'`
- `prog -u xxyy -f 'file.md' -cd 'Foo bar baz'`

Where as using subparsers, they would become something like (which I don't want, **correct me if I am wrong**)-

- `prog get -g xxyy`
- `prog create -c xxyy -d 'Hello World'`

**EDIT 2**
I figured out how to have mutually exclusive arguements using `add_mutually_exclusive_group`

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Mutex')
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('-g')
group.add_argument('-c')
group.add_argument('-u')
group.add_argument('-del')
group.add_argument('-rm')
```

**EDIT 3**
I am not able to get the *subparse* work. The following code (working with a subset) throws the error `error: invalid choice: 'world' (choose from '-m', '-f')` if the command is `$ python3 parse2.py -c hello -m world`

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Mutex')
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group.add_argument('-g')
group.add_argument('-c')
subparser = parser.add_subparsers()
parser_a = subparser.add_parser('-m')
parser_b = subparser.add_parser('-f')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

**EDIT 4**
I have almost solved my issue with the following -

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
sp = parser.add_subparsers(dest='main') # , required=True) in Py3.7
sp.required = True    # in py 3.6
p1 = sp.add_parser('get')
p1.add_argument('id')

p2 = sp.add_parser('update')
p2.add_argument('id')
p2.add_argument('-f', required=True)
p2.add_argument('-cd')

p3 = sp.add_parser('create')
p3.add_argument('name')
p3.add_argument('-d', required=True)
p3_mutex = p3.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
p3_mutex.add_argument('-f')
p3_mutex.add_argument('-m')

p4 = sp.add_parser('delete')
p4.add_argument('id')

p5 = sp.add_parser('remove')
p5.add_argument('id')
p5.add_argument('-r', required=True)

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

However I want to know if it is possible to add the `add_mutually_exclusive_group` for `get`, `delete`, `create`, `update` and `remove` or do I have to do that using `if` conditions?

Comment: Show us what you've tried with subparsers.  Just translate your description into the appropriate `add_subparsers`, `add_parser` and `add_argument` calls.  The fit should be straight forward.

Comment: @hpaulj the challenge with subparser is that, they themselves don't take any values, the parsers inside them would. That was the stopping point for me. For example, in my case I want to be able to execute like this - `prog -g xxyy`, `prog -c xxyy -d 'Hello World'`, `prog rm xxyy -r 'file.md'`. But using subparser they will become something like `prog get -g xxyy` and so on.

Comment: Why not 'get xxyy', and 'create xxyy -d 2'.  Any ways, if you don't like subparsers, then you need to do your own testing, and figure out a way telling your users the constraints.

Comment: I explored adding 'inclusive' and other groupings in a bug issue.  Doing the testing isn't too bad, but user interface is too big of a job.

Comment: @hpaulj actually I am okay with `prog get xxyy`, `prog create xxyy -d 'xxzz'` . I would in fact welcome that. DO subparsers allow you to do this ? I had formed the opinion that in case of subparsers get wont accept any values so we will have to again add a -g after get like `prog get -g 'xxyy'`. But from your comments it looks like subparsers allow accepting values. Do you have an example for that?

Comment: The 'xxyy' string would be accepted as a `positional` argument.

Comment: @hpaulj could you take one last look at EDIT 4, you have almost solved my issue. I was just wondering if I can make the parsers in the subparser mutually exclusive, I mean they do throw an error if i try to use them together, but its an `unrecognized arguments` error and not the error that mutually_exclusive_groups explicitly gives about not using them together.

Comment: Subparsers is already mutually exclusive.  You can only use one of the choices.  It is like defining a positional argument with a choices parameter.

Comment: @hpaulj yeah, I saw that while running some cases. Functionally its perfect. Its just the error message that isn't specific about not using them together. Instead it says something about `unrecognized arguments`. This is probably asking too much, but is there a workaround for that?

Comment: An `uncrecognized arguments` error should list which strings it doesn't recognize.  If you specify `prog delete id1 get id2` parsing is passed to `p4`, which handles `id1`, and puts `get id2` in the unrecognized list.  The main parser doesn't do any more parsing.  It just passes on any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A start of a subparser version:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
sp = parser.add_subparsers(dest='main') # , required=True) in Py3.7
sp.required = True    # in py 3.6
p1 = sp.add_parser('get')
p1.add_argument('xxyy')

p2 = sp.add_parser('update')
p2.add_argument('xxyy')
p2.add_argument('-r', required=True)
p2.add_argument('--cd')
# and so forth
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

sample runs

```
0914:~/mypy$ python3 stack53307678.py -h
usage: stack53307678.py [-h] {get,update} ...

positional arguments:
  {get,update}

optional arguments:
  -h, --help    show this help message and exit
0914:~/mypy$ python3 stack53307678.py get abc
Namespace(main='get', xxyy='abc')
0914:~/mypy$ python3 stack53307678.py update abc -r foo --cd x
Namespace(cd='x', main='update', r='foo', xxyy='abc')
```

Comment: that helped me almost solve my problem. I have added an **EDIT 4** that shows the code that does what I mention in the post earlier. I just want to know now if i have to use `if` conditions to make sure that `get`, `create`, `update`, `remove`, `delete` are NOT used together, or is it possible to have another `add_mutually_exclusive_group` on top to achieve this? I was fiddling with trying to integrate `add_mutually_exclusive_group` on top but couldn't figure out how to.