# argparse action menu with variable options

Tags: python, menu, action, argparse

I'm trying to build a program that takes the first argument as an action (like `program list`, `program create`, `program delete`, etc.), and then uses the rest of the provided options in context to the action (like `-c`, `--all`, etc.).

How can I define the same optional argument several times, for each action I define in the first argument?

Comment: You want to be able to give the same argument, multiple times in the same execution? With custom values each time (not just a counter)?

Comment: You could use subparsers.  They are documented, and have been discussed on SO a lot.  The latest example I gave is https://stackoverflow.com/a/53324772/901925.  If you don't like typing the same argument for several subparsers, you could use copy-n-paste in your editor, or write a utility function to do it for you.  There is also a `parents` mechanism, but often that seems to cause more problems than benefits.

Comment: or if the rest are the same, you start with a `positional` with `choices`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@hpaulj`'s comment helped me solve this. I've used subparsers and created separated contexts to store a config for each main action that I have in my script.

An example can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53324772/901925

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("action", type=str, help="action like create or delete")
parser.add_argument("-c", action="count", default=0)
```

in this case, the first argument given without -c will be stored in `action` variable.